# change the class name of a when mp3 finishes to play

Tags: javascript, jplayer

I am using jplayer. When the mp3 finishes, I want to change the class name from "stop" to "play". How can I do that in jplayer?

```
<div id="topid">
    <a class="stop" onclick="play('test1.mp3');" href="javascript:;"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `$.jPlayer.event.ended` event. I mean, come on, read the [docs](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-events).

Usage example from the same link:

```
$("#repeat-on").click( function() {
  $("#jpId").bind($.jPlayer.event.ended + ".jp-repeat", function(event) { // Using ".jp-repeat" namespace so we can easily remove this event
    $(this).jPlayer("play"); // Add a repeat behaviour so media replays when it ends. (Loops)
  });
  return false;
});
```